# PG-13 JavaScript automated machine

Tags: javascript

I have this problem from the book "Javascript for Kids" by Nick Morgan.
"You’ve been asked by the local movie theater managers to
Implement some JavaScript for a new automated system
They’re building. They want to be able to work out whether
Someone is allowed into a PG-13 movie or not.

The rules are as follows: if someone is 13 or over, they’re allowed
in under any circumstances. If they’re not over 13, they are only allowed if they are accompanied by an adult.

I wrote the following simple code:

```
var age = 12;
var accompanied = true;
var allowed = (age >= 13) || ((age < 13) && accompanied);
```

Now for `age = 6` and `accompanied = true`, it works.

But for the same age and `accompanied = false`, it shows the value of allowed as `true` as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm [unable to reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/cashdm6p/). Are you sure you're setting the new values before you check them?

Comment: i am practicing this in console of the chrome browser.

Comment: Make sure you're reassigning `allowed` after changing the values of `age` and `accompanied`.

Comment: Show code that isn't working, not code that is.

Comment: ok, after writing the above code. i am writing this to check:
age = 6;
accompanied = true;
allowed;
true

Comment: @Goldensquare: the value of `allowed` doesn't automatically change when you reassign some other variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking if they are allowed after chaning the variables? If not then you would just be calling the previous result. Like this:

```
var age = 12;
var accompanied = true;
var allowed = (age >= 13) || ((age < 13) && accompanied);
Console.log(allowed);

var age 6;
var accompanied = false;
Console.log(allowed);
```

If this is not the case then it may be something todo with how you are running it or your editor or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const age = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos años tienes?"));
const acompanied = confirm("Vas a compañado de una persona adulta?");

if (age >= 13 || (age < 13 && acompanied)) {
  alert("Puedes entrar");
} else {
  alert("No puedes entrar");
}
```

Comment: Puedes usar esta función

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information